# Bootstrap Multiple collapse panels within side-navigation bar

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, I am building a web application with ASP.NET MVC5 using Bootstrap and jQuery.

I have the users add groupings to a 'cart' contained in a collapsible side navbar:

```
<div id="cart" class="sidebar-nav">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="groupAddBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add New Grouping</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cartItems">
        @Html.Partial("CartPartialView", Session["ShoppingCart"])
    </div>
</div>
```

Within this cart, I am rendering a partial view that contains the cart items and it is updated with new items via an AJAX call to my HomeController:

```
@using Project.Models
@model Cart

@foreach (CartGroup group in Model.CartGroups)
{
    <br />
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading CartItem collapsed" role="button" id="@(group.GroupName + "_header")" data-toggle="collapse" href="#@(group.GroupName + "_body")">
                        <label class="groupNameLbl">@group.GroupName</label>
                        <div class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right RemoveGroupBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" id="@(group.GroupName +"_body")">
                        <div class="panel-body">

                            @if (group.CartItems != null && group.CartItems.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (CartItem item in group.CartItems)
                                {
                                    <div class="row">
                                            <div class="panel panel-success">
                                                <div class="panel-heading CartItemBody">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" role="button" id="@(group.GroupName + "_" + item.CartItemID + "_" + item.CartItemSubID + "_" + item.CartItemSubSubID)" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#@(group.GroupName + "_" + item.CartItemID + "_" + item.CartItemSubID + "_" + item.CartItemSubSubID + "_body")" aria-controls="#@(group.GroupName + "_" + item.CartItemID + "_" + item.CartItemSubID + "_" + item.CartItemSubSubID + "_body")"></span> <label>@item.CartItemName</label>
                                                    <div class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right RemoveCartItemBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="panel-body collapse" id="@(group.GroupName + "_" + item.CartItemID + "_" + item.CartItemSubID + "_" + item.CartItemSubSubID + "_body")">
                                                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><strong>CartItemProp1</strong></td>
                                                            <td><strong>@item.CartItemID</strong>   <i>@item.CartItemProp1</i></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><strong>CartItemProp2</strong></td>
                                                            <td><strong>@item.CartItemSubID</strong>  <i>@item.CartItemProp2</i></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><strong>CartItemProp3</strong></td>
                                                            <td><strong>@item.CartItemSubSubID</strong>   <i>@item.CartItemProp3</i></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <p>There are currently no items in this grouping.</p>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**The Problem:**
The first grouping that is added and all subsequent items added to this group expand/collapse as they should. Each item will display it's contents when the span with the glyphicon is clicked.

Any additional groupings or items added WILL NOT collapse/expand. The IDs are being generated correctly and there is definitely an event firing when the group/items are clicked but they do not animate as they should. If I remove the topmost, initial group the second group left in the cart will still not expand/collapse.

I do not know if this is related to the dynamic nature of the add/remove functions of the cart items, but it will not work even on a page refresh. I have reworked the markup several times with no luck. Any advice would be appreciated.

**SOLVED:** The IDs for the panel groups are being built using Razor. It is necessary to remove/replace any IDs with spaces in them: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Ended up being a very silly problem.

Comment: Is the first grouping added from the backend or is it added dynamically via ajax?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment. The first grouping is added dynamically via AJAX. Each grouping is added in the same manner and each is being produced with a guaranteed unique ID.

Comment: Coming up on 5 years later, this code is gross.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** The IDs for the panel groups are being built using Razor. It is necessary to remove/replace any IDs with spaces in them: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

This can be achieved without any effect on the displayed HTML by simply replacing the space with an underscore:

```
    foreach (CartGroup group in Model.CartGroups)
{

     var GroupNameID = group.GroupName.Replace(" ", "_");

    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel-group" id="@(GroupNameID)">
```

Ended up being a very silly problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding HTML to your page after it is already rendered.
The "collapse/expand" functionality comes from bootstrap.
They way this works is that bootstrap executes JavaScript when the page is ready and adds event listener to all elements with a certain class.

Since you are adding html after the JavaScript was already executed the bootstrap functionality will not work.

You must execute the JavaScript for the new parts yourself after adding them to the page. Add the following to your JavaScript ajax method after adding the new element(s) to the page.

```
$('.collapse').collapse();
```

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp

Comment: No dice. I tried adding it in the AJAX call and the partial view.